# batch rename files with ids intact

Tags: bash, rename

i have a directory listing like

```
seascaperecovered0088crop.jpg 
seascaperecovered0096crop.jpg
seascaperecovered0098crop.jpg
seascaperecovered0101crop.jpg
seascaperecovered0103crop.jpg
seascaperecovered0105crop.jpg
seascaperecovered0107crop.jpg
seascaperecovered0112crop.jpg
seascaperecovered0119crop.jpg
seascaperecovered0122crop.jpg
```

and i want to rename all files as seen here:

```
seascape_0122.jpg
```

i have tried something like this:

```
for f in `ls | egrep 'seascaperecovered.*\.jpg'`; 
do mv $f ${f/seascaperecovered/seascape}; 
done
```

i have read that you can do this with mv, rename, sed, awk, etc.
can someone point me to the easiest (and clearest, hopefully) way of accomplishing this in UNIX?
FWIW, I am ssh'd into a Linux machine and running a bash shell.

thanks,
jml

Comment: i would also be interested in why my example wouldn't work.  i get a number of errors like:  "mv: cannot stat `\033[33mseascaperecovered0088crop.jpg\033[0m': No such file or directory"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very straightforward:

```
for i in seascaperecovered*.jpg; do A=${i/crop/}; mv $i ${A/recovered/_}; done
```

(Put `echo` before the `mv` first for a dry run.)

Comment: nice! what about removing the "crop" bit?  should i pipe again?

Comment: Sneaky, I almost noticed that too late :-)

Comment: No prob. I do this sort of stuff pretty regularly, and I'm always so happy I have a Bash in Windows; I really couldn't imagine life without one!

Comment: That is pretty amazing, I didn't know you could do that in Bash. What is this operation called, so I can read more about it?

Comment: @Chriszuma: Which operation? For for-do-done loop is a Bash built-in construction (`man bash`). The curly braces fall under "parameter substitution" (or something like that).

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the curly braces. That is a very powerful tool I'd never seen before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With bash regular expressions

```
for file in *; do 
  [[ "$file" =~ [0-9]+ ]] && mv "$file" seascape_${BASH_REMATCH[0]}.jpg 
done
```