# Rename all files in directory from $filename_h to $filename_half?

Tags: bash, shell

Dead simple.

How do I rename

```
05_h.png
06_h.png
```

to

```
05_half.png
06_half.png
```

At least, I think it's simple, but it's hard to Google for this kind of thing unless you already know.

Thanks....

Answer (score 400, accepted):

Just use bash, no need to call external commands.

```
for file in *_h.png
do
  mv "$file" "${file/_h.png/_half.png}"
done
```

**Do not add `#!/bin/sh`**

For those that need that one-liner:

```
for file in *.png; do mv "$file" "${file/_h.png/_half.png}"; done
```

Comment: Nice use of bash's built-in string replacement rather than sed

Comment: is file/_h.png/_half.png regex?

Comment: No, the format is this: 
${string/substring/substitution} – "substitute ﬁrst occurrence".
For more info check this cheat sheet (section "strings"): http://bruxy.regnet.cz/linux/bash_cheatsheet/bash_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I was able to make minimal changes and use it to remove "@1x.png" from lots of files at once. Here's that: for file in *.png; do mv "$file" "${file/@1x.png/.png}"; done

Comment: Any reasons for `Do not add #!/bin/sh` ? I tried both working with/ without this statement.

Comment: @Ryan It's really a comment so it doesn't matters if you use it or not. So, Maybe he said that because it is useless to type that line here.

Comment: @Ryan @Ishan Jain In fact it indicates the backend shell that must execute the script. sh and bash are different shells so it may affect the script behavior and syntax. Since the script uses a bash built-in string replacement you should add the header `#!/bin/bash`. This said, bash is normally the default shell in many computers so you won't find many differences :D You can find more information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash)

Answer (score 82):

Try `rename` command:

```
rename 's/_h.png/_half.png/' *.png
```

**Update:**

example usage:

create some content

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
$ cd /tmp/foo
$ touch one_h.png two_h.png three_h.png
$ ls 
one_h.png  three_h.png  two_h.png
```

test solution:

```
$ rename 's/_h.png/_half.png/' *.png
$ ls
one_half.png  three_half.png  two_half.png
```

Comment: @CarolineAlexiou: what was the problem? command not found? Did something else than rename? Please be more specific so we can help.

Comment: @CarolineAlexiou: I added example test session. Please try it. You probably have some typo. What is the output of `ls` ? what is the `rename ...` you try?

Comment: I tested it with a dummy example and it worked. I am pretty sure I didnt have a typo though. Will write back if I find what was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work in bash on Mac, fwiw. `rename` is not a standard Unix tool.

Comment: @tandrewnichols, try out [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) - once installed, rename becomes available in seconds with `brew install rename`

Comment: Understood. I already have homebrew. Just pointing that it's non-standard, so it won't work by default in every bash environment.

Comment: just to clearify, the right syntax is rename 'search_word' 'replace_word' *.png

Comment: as for me rename didn't work with `'s//'` - I referenced man and there was simple synopsis: `rename [options] expression replacement file...`, on CentOS 7 , version: `rename from util-linux 2.23.2`

Comment: keep in mind that `.` matches ANY character, not just a dot – for literal dot, use `\.` instead

Comment: This solution enables using multiple vars if double quoting substitution pattern, the marked one don't. i.e. `rename "s/${VAR1}_h.png/${VAR2}_half.png/" *.png`

Comment: awesome command - basically it works like `sed` but instead of a text file filenames are used as input

Answer (score 15):

```
for f in *.png; do
  fnew=`echo $f | sed 's/_h.png/_half.png/'`
  mv $f $fnew
done
```

Or in one-liner:

```
for f in *.png; do mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed 's/_h.png$/_half.png/g')"; done
```

Comment: This is great for doing a dry run beforehand. I first replaced `mv $f $fnew` with `echo $fnew` as the second line to make sure the output looks sane.

Answer (score 15):

Are you looking for a pure bash solution? There are many approaches, but here's one.

```
for file in *_h.png ; do mv "$file" "${file%%_h.png}_half.png" ; done
```

This presumes that the only files in the current directory that end in `_h.png` are the ones you want to rename.

Much more specifically

```
for file in 0{5..6}_h.png ; do mv "$file" "${file/_h./_half.}" ; done
```

Presuming those two examples are your only. files.

For the general case, file renaming in [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix)
[been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086513/batch-rename-files-with-ids-intact) [covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911301/rename-multiple-files-shell/6912021#6912021)
[before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224766/bash-rename-files).

Comment: Long live one-liners !!

Answer (score 8):

Use the `rename` utility written in perl.
Might be that it is not available by default though...

```
$ touch 0{5..6}_h.png

$ ls
05_h.png  06_h.png

$ rename 's/h/half/' *.png

$ ls
05_half.png  06_half.png
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar question: 
In the manual, it describes rename as

```
rename [option] expression replacement file
```

so you can use it in this way

```
rename _h _half *.png
```

In the code:
'_h' is the expression that you are looking for. 
'_half' is the pattern that you want to replace with. 
'*.png' is the range of files that you are looking for your possible target files.

Hope this can help c:

Answer (score 5):

```
for i in *_h.png ; do
  mv $i `echo "$i"|awk -F'.' '{print $1"alf."$2}'`
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `rename` utility:

```
rc@bvm3:/tmp/foo $ touch 05_h.png 06_h.png
rc@bvm3:/tmp/foo $ rename 's/_h/_half/' * 
rc@bvm3:/tmp/foo $ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 rc rc 0 2011-09-17 00:15 05_half.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 rc rc 0 2011-09-17 00:15 06_half.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach can be manually using  batch rename option

Right click on the file -> File Custom Commands -> Batch Rename
and you can replace h. with half.

This will work for linux based gui using WinSCP etc

Answer (score 2):

One liner:
`for file in *.php ; do mv "$file" "_$file" ; done`

Answer (score 2):

Although the *answer set* is complete, I need to add another missing one.

```
for i in *_h.png;
  do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'_' -f1`
  echo "Executing of name $name" 
  mv "$i" "${name}_half.png"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to rename the prefix of files and I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126090/473818) with a solution like this:

```sh
for i in h_*; do mv ${i/#h_/half_}; done
```

> If pattern begins with #, it must match at the beginning of the
> expanded value of parameter. If pattern begins with %, it must match
> at the end of the expanded value of parameter.

from `man bash`