# Remove pattern from filenames

Tags: unix, rename

how can I remove the word "myfile" in a list of filenames with this structure?

```
mywork_myfile_XSOP.txt
mywork_myfile_ATTY.txt
mywork_myfile_ATPY.txt
```

Desired_output:

```
mywork_XSOP.txt
mywork_ATTY.txt
mywork_ATPY.txt
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest method is to use the common `rename` command which is available in most Unices.

```
rename 's/^mywork_myfile_/mywork_/' *
```

This of course expects you to be on the directory of the files. This will not overwrite files. If you want that, just pass the -f option. Also, take note that there's multiple versions of `rename` out there which may have different options.

Comment: does not work for macOS

Comment: I think there are two `rename` implementations: one is part of Linux kernel utilities and the other part of Perl. I think neither are available on MacOS by default. You may want to try a variation of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47372/22817

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7451880/1983854) on "Rename all files in "Rename all files in directory from $filename_h to $filename_half?", this can be a way:

```
for file in mywork_myfile*txt
do
   mv "$file" "${file/_myfile/}"
done
```

Note that it uses the bash string operations as follows:

```
$ file="mywork_myfile_XSOP.txt"
$ echo ${file/_myfile/}
mywork_XSOP.txt
```

Comment: Well, this *is* the cleanest way. Although it is bash-specific and won't work in other shells, not even other Posix-style ones, that's probably OK these days. Everyone ships bash.

Comment: The question is tagged `bash`, so I wouldn't worry about POSIX compatibility. That said, in general, one cannot assume that `bash` is the system shell (Ubuntu) or that the system shell is a current version of `bash` (Mac OS X).

Comment: Well, good points, tho actually the question is *not* tagged bash.

Comment: It was when I commented.

Comment: My fault, I edited the question and added the `bash` as per the kind of question. Removing it.

Answer (score 3):

This would work in any Posix shell...

```bash
#!/bin/sh

for i
  in mywork_myfile_XSOP.txt \
     mywork_myfile_ATTY.txt \
     mywork_myfile_ATPY.txt; do
       set -x
       mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed -e s/myfile_//)"
       set +x
done
```

Comment: Good one as well. Note also that it is normally recommended to use `$()` instead of ````

Comment: Both arguments to `mv` should be quoted as well.