# BASH : Add a string to all file names in a folder

Tags: bash, rename, mv

I have a folder with several files :

```
1-1.csv
1-2.csv
2-1.csv
```

And I want to rename them this way :

```
1-1-hist.csv
1-2-hist.csv
2-1-hist.csv
```

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450818/rename-all-files-in-directory-from-filename-h-to-filename-half) I tried the following :

```
for file in *.csv
do
  mv "$file" "${file/.csv/-hist.csv}"
done
```

But file names don't change and my terminal says :

```
mv: '1-1.csv' and '1-1.csv' are the same file
mv: '1-2.csv' and '1-2.csv' are the same file
mv: '2-1.csv' and '2-1.csv' are the same file
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT :**

```
rename 's/.csv/-hist.csv/' *.csv
```

did the job. Even if I don't know what did not work in the first attempt...

Comment: What are the underscores meant to do in the substitution?  It seems like the shell is trying to match them, not finding them and therefore, not doing the substitution.

Comment: Remove the underscores.

Comment: I tried without the underscores but it is still the same...? for file in *
do
  mv "$file" "${file/.csv/-hist.csv}"
done

Comment: The command, as it is now in the question, ought to work in `bash`.