# Rename all files in a folder using bash

Tags: bash, file, rename

I have a folder with many files named as '00001.sdf', '00002.sdf' and so on. I want to add an 'M' character at the beginning of each file name, like this 'M00001.sdf', 'M00002.sdf. How can I do this using a bash command?

Comment: I copy pasted the title of your question in google and [Rename all files in directory from $filename_h to $filename_half?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450818/rename-all-files-in-directory-from-filename-h-to-filename-half) was the first result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively if you have `perl` version of the `rename` utility:

```
rename 's/^0/M0/' *
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
for f in * ; do mv "$f" "M$f" ; done
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks!

Comment: Well.. You can accept and close this thread if it solved your case#

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
ls -1 *.sdf | awk '{ system("mv "$0" M"$0) }'
```