# Rename multiple files on linux

Tags: regex, linux, command-line, rename

So I have a folder with several files named like this:

```
name_file_00000.jpg  
name_file_00001.jpg  
name_file_00002.jpg  
name_file_00003.jpg  
...  
name_file_00080.jpg
```

And I want to rename this files like this:

```
name_file_00000.jpg ==> name_file_00001.jpg  
name_file_00001.jpg ==> name_file_00002.jpg  
name_file_00002.jpg ==> name_file_00003.jpg  
...  
name_file_00080.jpg ==> name_file_00081.jpg
```

How can I do that in Linux with a single command?

Comment: Just write a shell script to calculate the expected file name and do `mv` move command.

Comment: with a for loop and the mv command in a shellscript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename all files in directory from $filename\_h to $filename\_half?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450818/rename-all-files-in-directory-from-filename-h-to-filename-half)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: a simple for loop, which loops from 80 to 00 and ueses the mv command.
It has to loop backwards, because you can't rename the `file_name_00000.jpg` to `file_name_00001.jpg` while `file_name_00001.jpg` isn't renamed already.

```
for i in `seq -sw 0 80`; do mv "file_name_000$i.jpg file_name_000$[i+1].jpg"; done
```