# Rename .txt files

Tags: bash, shell

Looking for help with the following code. I have a folder titled data, with 6 subfolders (folder1, folder2, etc). Each folder has a text file I want to rename to "homeworknotes" keeping the .txt extension.

Used notes before for short:

So far I have the following code:

```
for file in data/*/*.txt; do
mv $file "notes"
done
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename all files in directory from $filename\_h to $filename\_half?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450818/rename-all-files-in-directory-from-filename-h-to-filename-half)

Answer (score 4):

### find

You can use `find` command with `-execdir` that will execute command of your choice in a directory where file matching pattern is:

```
find data -type f -name '*.txt' -execdir mv \{\} notes.txt \;
```

- `data` is path to directory where `find` should look for matching files recursively
- `-type f` look only for files, not directories
- `-name '*.txt'` match anything that ends with `.txt`
- `-execdir mv \{\} notes.txt` run command `mv {} notes.txt` in directory where file was found; where `{}` is original filename found by `find`.

### bash

EDIT1: To do this without `find` you need to handle recursive directory traversal (unless you have fixed directory layout). In `bash` you can set following shell options with `shopt -s` command:

- `extglob` - extended globbing support (allows to write extended globs like `**`; see "Pathname Expansion" in `man bash`)
- `globstar` - allows `**` in pathname expansion; `**/` will match any directories and their subdirectories (see "Pathname Expansion" in `man bash`).
- `nullglob` - allows patterns that match no files (in case there's a directory without any .txt file)

Following script will traverse directories under `data/` and rename .txt files to `notes.txt`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob globstar nullglob
for f in data/**/*.txt ; do
    mv $f $(dirname $f)/notes.txt
done
```

- `mv $f $(dirname $f)/notes.txt` moves (renames) file; `$f` contains matched path so e.g. `data/folder1/day4notes.txt` and `$(dirname $f)` gets directory where that file is - in this case `data/folder1` so we just append `/notes.txt` to that.

EDIT2: If you are absolutely positive that you want to do this only in first level of subdirectories under `data/` you can omit `extglob` and `globstar` (and if you know there's at least one .txt in each directory then also `nullglob`) and go ahead with pattern you posted; but you still need to use `mv $f $(dirname $f)/notes.txt` to rename file.

NOTE: When experimenting with things like these always make backup beforehand. If you have multiple .txt files in any of directories they all will get renamed to `notes.txt` so you might lose data in that case.

Comment: @swampmonkey updated my answer to do it in bash loop; although I recommend you to stick with find when it comes to traversing directory structures.