# batch rename files and folders at once

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I got help regarding the following question:
[batch rename files with ids intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086513/batch-rename-files-with-ids-intact)

It's a great example of how to rename specific files in a group, but I am wondering if there is a similar script I could use to do the following:

1. I have a group of nested folders and files within a root directory that contain [myprefix_foldername] and [myprefix_filename.ext]
2. I would like to rename all of the folders *and* files to [foldername] and [filename.ext]

Can I use a similar methodology to what is found in the post above?

Thanks!
jml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, quite easily, with [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

```
find rootDir -name "myprefix_*"
```

This will give you a list of all files and folders in `rootDir` that start with `myprefix_`. From there, it's a short jump to a batch rename:

```
find rootDir -name "myprefix_*" | while read f
do
  echo "Moving $f to ${f/myprefix_/}"
  mv "$f" "${f/myprefix_/}"
done
```

**EDIT:** `IFS` added per http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html

**EDIT 2:** `IFS` removed in favor of `while read`.

**EDIT 3:** As bos points out, you may need to change `while read f` to `while read -d $'\n' f` if your version of Bash still doesn't like it.

Comment: what if there are spaces in the folder names?  it seems to fail under those circumstances...  let me know if you need more specifics.

Comment: I can't see why it would fail. Did you remember to put the quotes around `$f` and `${f/myprefix_/}`? Let me see how it is failing.

Comment: the echo fails...  i wanted to check it with that first.

Comment: Did you copy it directly from my answer? It seems to be working fine for me. What is the exact filename it fails on?

Comment: it's a folder- i have a folder named 'myprefix_foldername Project', and it reads out 'Moving Project to Project'

Comment: Oooooooohhhhhhhhhhhhhh........ Okay yeah, the `for` command is splitting up the space-laden filenames. Easiest solution I could find it to put `IFS="\n"` in your script, as seen here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-scripting-add-a-character-to-a-line-134724/#post700774

Comment: @jml - I came up with a slightly less messy way that doesn't require `IFS`. See edited answer.

Comment: What we don't know here is the version of jml's bash. Older bashes has SPACE as delimiter for "read", while newer have \n. If jml uses an old version, change `while read f` into `while read -d '\n' f`.

Comment: @Chriszuma - thanks a million.  also; i'm on osx 10.7; i think that the bash shell should be just fine for usage of 'while'.